# Lightroom causes system wide connectivity issue

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, connection, adobe-lightroom

## Problem

When starting LR all network activity on my WiFi connection stops (as observed in the "Performance" tab of the Task manager) and I can no longer access anything from the web (websites through a browser, LR Mobile in LR, Skype etc).

*How can I fix this, or further diagnose what is ging on?*

## Symptoms

After a short while the WiFi will be shown as having `No Internet` in the taskbar network overview.

Connectivity can intermittently resume while LR is running for short periods of time, but only resumes as normal once LR is closed (including the diagnostic report showing that all is fine).
This does not seem to happen with other Adobe Creative Cloud applications.

## Additional Diagnostics

Additional information gathered through tools.

### Windows Network Diagnostics

The WND indicates that `Windows Sockets registry entries required for network connectivity are missing`, but the issue cannot automatically be resolved.

### Chrome Connectivity Diagnostics

Shows that an Internet Connection is available

```
SUMMARY
Test Name: Chrome Internet Disconnected Test
Test ID: 0
Test verdict: No problem detected

CRITERIA
Percentage of TCP sockets that return Internet disconnected status codes below which a no problem verdict is rendered: 100
Percentage of TCP sockets that return Internet disconnected status codes equal to or above which a problem verdict is rendered: 100


DETAILS
Thu Mar 24 2016 11:13:53 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time) -  About to attempt TCP connection #/hostname/port: 0 / gduiwqluca-ccd-testing-v4.metric.gstatic.com / 80
Thu Mar 24 2016 11:13:53 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time) - Setting TCP timeout length (msec): 10000
Thu Mar 24 2016 11:13:53 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time) - Creating a TCP socket, number/host/port:  5 / gduiwqluca-ccd-testing-v4.metric.gstatic.com / 80
Thu Mar 24 2016 11:13:53 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time) - TCP connection established with host/port/status code: gduiwqluca-ccd-testing-v4.metric.gstatic.com / 80 / -105
Thu Mar 24 2016 11:13:53 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time) - # 0 Chrome Internet connection test returned TCP status code: -105
Thu Mar 24 2016 11:13:53 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time) -  About to attempt TCP connection #/hostname/port: 1 / jdkdrrfbzm-ccd-testing-v4.metric.gstatic.com / 80
Thu Mar 24 2016 11:13:53 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time) - Setting TCP timeout length (msec): 10000
Thu Mar 24 2016 11:13:53 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time) - Creating a TCP socket, number/host/port:  6 / jdkdrrfbzm-ccd-testing-v4.metric.gstatic.com / 80
Thu Mar 24 2016 11:13:53 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time) - TCP connection established with host/port/status code: jdkdrrfbzm-ccd-testing-v4.metric.gstatic.com / 80 / -105
Thu Mar 24 2016 11:13:53 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time) - # 1 Chrome Internet connection test returned TCP status code: -105
```

But no DNS Server can be reached

```
SUMMARY
Test Name: Resolver Present Test
Test ID: 3
Test verdict: Problem detected

CRITERIA
DNS resolver test performs a single DNS query and returns a failing result if a valid response is not returned.
DNS resolver test performs a single DNS query and returns a passing result if a valid response is returned.


DETAILS
Thu Mar 24 2016 11:13:53 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time) - Attempting to resolve hostname: ccd-testing-v4.gstatic.com
Thu Mar 24 2016 11:13:53 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time) - DNS server returned DNS query results.
Thu Mar 24 2016 11:13:53 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time) - DNS server returned problem status code: -105
```

### Software and Hardware Versions Involved

- Surface Pro 4
- Windows 10 (Version 10.0.10586 Build 10586)
- Lightroom CC 2015.5

## Things I have tried that did not help

- Downgrading the LR version to 2015.4
- Turning off WiFi and using a tethered Bluetooth connection via my phone
- Closing the Adobe Creative Cloud application and killing all related processes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is only indirectly related to Lightroom. It seems that my attached external USB 3.0 HD (WD My Passport Ultra) is the actual culprit.

Apparently there is an issue with interference between 2.4GHz WiFi and USB 3.0 on Surfaces ([described in this Article](http://www.lovemysurface.net/wifi-problems-on-surface-pro-4/), and in this [MS Community discussion](https://forums.adobe.com/message/8618377#8618377)).

Lightroom naturally tries to access photos which are located on the external HD and starts to cause interference. 
I can also reproduce the problem by manually accessing files on the HD.

Long term solutions (that are described in the mentioned article) are

- use an external HD that does not cause interference (better shielded / USB2)
- use a 5GHz WiFi

My temporary workaround is to use USB tethering through my phone.