# How to avoid interference between USB3 and WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, usb-3

This is somewhat a follow up question to my [previous question that turned out to be related to this issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1056551/lightroom-causes-system-wide-connectivity-issue/1056881#1056881).

It seems that for some devices (e.g., the Microsoft Surface Pro 4), connecting a USB3 device can cause interference with 2.4GHz WiFi connections.

How can I avoid this interference? Ideally without replacing the hardware (e.g., using a USB2 hard drive or a 5GHz router both both could Avoid the problem).

Answer (score 0):

If speed is not an issue a simple solution is to use a connection that limits the USB device to USB2 (or lower), e.g., a hub or a cable that does not support USB3 yet.

Comment: I'm posting this as my current workaround, but I'd be happy to hear and accept better solutions).

Answer (score -1):

Simple: wrap your USB device, the circuitry or cover including the cable in tin foil or similar signal shielding